# How set Flex server location for BlazeDS maven build

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven, blazeds

As a first step getting a Hello World Flex-to-Java application to compile and run I followed:

```
http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/configuration-eclipse-for-blazeds/
```

and it ran successfully. However now I wish to automate the build in Maven. Does anyone know how to specify the Flex Server location in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a bit off topic, but you will find a good Flex/Maven integration together with [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/). See documentation [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.projectsetup.html#setup.maven) (the "contextRoot" node in the pom.xml is what you are looking for). And you would also be able, among other things, to automate ActionScript3 beans generation (based on your Java entities/beans) with the same tool, see [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.gas3.html#gas3.maven).